# Show tooltip when user moves mouse on column name of bootstrap-vue table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tooltip, bootstrap-vue

I have a bootstrap-vue table that looks like this;

[image]

Here's the code for the table;

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        // Note 'isActive' is left out and will not appear in the rendered table
        fields: [
          {
            key: 'last_name',
            sortable: true
          },
          {
            key: 'first_name',
            sortable: false
          },
          {
            key: 'age',
            label: 'Person age',
            sortable: true,
            // Variant applies to the whole column, including the header and footer
            variant: 'danger'
          }
        ],
        items: [
          { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
          { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
          { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
          { isActive: true, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

This is what I want to do. When user moves his mouse to `First Name` column name cell, I want to show a tooltip that says "Click to sort First Name".

I am using vue v2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [b-tooltip](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tooltip) component of **bootstrap-vue** you can do that like the code below:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields"></b-table>
    <!-- using "b-tooltip" component that targets the defined "id" in the fields of "b-table" -->
    <b-tooltip target="myHeader" triggers="hover" container="myHeader">
      Click to sort First Name
    </b-tooltip>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CompoTable",
  data() {
    return {
      // Note 'isActive' is left out and will not appear in the rendered table
      fields: [
        {
          key: 'last_name',
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          key: 'first_name',
          /* ------------------------------ */
          /* I changed sortable to "true" to make sorting */
          /* ------------------------------ */
          sortable: true,
          /* ------------------------------ */
          /* add this to add "id" to "th" tag related to "first name" */
          /* ------------------------------ */
          thAttr: {
            id: "myHeader"
          }
        },
        {
          key: 'age',
          label: 'Person age',
          sortable: true,
          // Variant applies to the whole column, including the header and footer
          variant: 'danger'
        }
      ],
      items: [
        { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
        { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
        { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
        { isActive: true, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Also you need [thAttr](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#field-definition-reference) field property to add **"id"** to the **first-name** column in your table definition.

Comment: Thanks. I'll study your answer. When I run the code snippet, I got error "{
  "message": "SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 21,
  "colno": 0
}"

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted and marked as correct answer. I have verified your answer to be correct. I don't know why there's an error when I run the code snippet but the answer is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure, try to remove the name of component to see that the error disappears or not. It does not give me any error in my local development environment.

Comment: Never mind. Your answer works anyway.

Comment: StackOverflow code snippets don't process Vue SFCs, so it can't be run here.